# Link to specific Tomboy note

Tags: panel, tomboy

I'm trying to link to a specific tomboy note from the panel or from the desktop. I don't really like the notifaction "click, dropdown, click" way for a specific note I'm using, so I want to be able to open it with one seperate button.

I couldn't find it on the website of Tomboy, nor did Google help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tomboy notes are saved in `~/.local/share/tomboy`. They have a `.note` ending.

To open a note from command line you can use `tomboy --open-note YOUR_NOTE`. The only problem is that they are not saved by their name but by some sort of hash.

Either you find out what note it is or you write a small script which opens a note based on a specific creation date or some other aspect. You could also have the script read the first line of the note for a specific string.

Comment: This works, but your 'problem' isn't there. I should've just read the manpage like a good boy: `open-note` takes note-title as argument, so `tomboy --open-note NOTE_TITLE` does the job. thanks ;)

Comment: Oh boy. Apparently I should've read the man page more carefully too. :p